# How do I make Byobu terminal open hyperlinks in browser when clicked?

Tags: byobu

Currently I need to right click, copy URL and paste link browser.

I have seen this question: [Terminal emulator left-click to open link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174596/terminal-emulator-left-click-to-open-link)

But it does not cover Byobu's config files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so, by holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and then click on the link, and that will open that link in the browser.

Comment: That works, thanks! How do I remap that to just click instead of Ctrl+click?

Comment: I really haven't done that, but take a look at [Many Buttons Mouse How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto), and this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#300203).